# What does the sentence mean in IELTS?

Tags: translation

When I doing my IELTS test, I found

> Write ONE WORD AND/OR A NUMBER for each answer

and in a blank

> Time at current address：_______

I filled in *fortnight*, because I think only one word or number should be filled in. But the answer is *2 weeks*, and actually there is *2 weeks* in the dialog. Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: *Two weeks* is definitely a word and a number.  That's what "and/or" means: a word or a number or a word AND a number.  But I think this question may be off-topic, since it's about why a particular IELTS question is scored the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it requested "a number and/or one word".

It sounds like maybe you thought that the answer is one word which is also a number.  But the test is asking for a number and/or a word -- this means either a number, a word, or a number and a word.  So, writing a number and a word is acceptable.

Your answer of "fortnight" is also correct, because a fortnight is two weeks, but you also could have written "two weeks".

Comment: Is using just "fortnight" like this correct? As an American English speaker, I don't use "fortnight" often, but I would never use month or week in this way. Always "time at current address: _one_ week", never "time at current address: week". I would expect fortnight to be used in the same way.

Comment: In American English we don't usually use "fortnight".  You're right that you normally wouldn't just say "fortnight".  You'd say "a fortnight", or maybe "one fortnight".